# "tlsv1 alert unknown ca" error when using new SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, pki, emq, digicert

I am configuring emqtt MQTT Broker with SSL/TLS certificates from Digicert. I had done the SSL configuration for the same broker some years back and it was fine. But when I configured the new broker installation with new certificates, I am getting "unknown CA" error.

This is the SSL settings:

```
mqtt.listener.ssl.keyfile = etc/certs/prod.key 
mqtt.listener.ssl.certfile = etc/certs/server.crt
mqtt.listener.ssl.cacertfile = etc/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
```

And this is the error I saw in the server logs:

```
[error] <0.27032.0> SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:97:Fatal error: unknown ca
```

Can this be an issue with the new CA certifcate? Maybe it requires more dependent certificates in chain?

**UPDATE**
This appears to be an OS issue.I got the following error when I tested the certificates using "openssl verify" in the server:

```
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

Verify is success on my local PC with the same command and same certificates

I updated the OS root certificates using "yum update ca-certificates", but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Hi Kiran, Did you found the solution to this? even I am getting the same error. In my case also it was working fine but after updating the SSL certificate I am getting this error message.

Comment: @AkashM please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause. Basically I had missed using one of the  CA certificates in the chain. The CA certificate I had was not enough. So I appended the missing CA certificate to the CA file I was using. I just used 'cat' command for this.

Comment: If this solves a problem, please mark this as an "answer".

Comment: Using this site I could easily get the intermediate certificate: https://tools.keycdn.com/certificate-chain

Comment: For those non linux users could you elaborate more on the use of Cat cmd and file appends to make your answer more complete.